# missing spanId and traceId in any log statements in doAfterTerminate or doOnSuccess block

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, micrometer-tracing

missing spanId and traceId in any log statements in **doAfterTerminate** or **doOnSuccess** block.

am using **spring boot 3.2 with webflux** with **micro meter tracing & observation**, below are tracing dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

even after adding below configs

```
Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
```

```
spring:
 logging:
   pattern:
       level: '%5p [${spring.application.name:}, %X{traceId:-}, %X{spanId:-}]'

management:
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://zipkin-server-url/api/v2/spans
  tracing:
    enabled: true
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
    propagation:
      type: b3
  metrics:
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        http:
          server:
            requests: true
```

any idea, what am missing here?

Comment: You also use Reactor 3.6, right? Try to remove `micrometer-tracing` and `micrometer-tracing-bom`, Boot manages these for you.